# Directional derivatives definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find using the definition of directional derivatives, all directions $(a,b)$, $n=(a,b),\|n\|=1$ such that the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ exists where
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)},  & \text{$(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I get $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(at,bt)-f(0,0)}t=\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)$, so $f'((0,0),(a,b))=f(a,b)$. Is this enough to show the solution?

Comment: I tried to edit the post but in some places for instance in limit at the end, I couldn't get what the OP wants to say?

Comment: Seems like your limit usually blows up. I'm not sure what your prime notation means.